# Find count of duplicate elements and create arrays of them

Tags: java, arrays, java1.4

i have a list of elements in array like `[121,122,121,122,123,121,122]` 
output should be arrays of all the duplicate elements like

```
[121,121,121]
[122,122,122]
[123]
```

I am limited to use *Java 1.4.*  This is going to be our last release in this version, the app runs on SAP J2EE server which supports only 1.4.

see the complete code from hint of @Subhrajyoti Majumder

the size prints 9 but when i iterate it is printing too many..
The output should be as following based on  delivery number

```
[a1,a2]
[a3,a4]
[a6]
[a7,a8,a9,a10]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried exactly?

Comment: Java 1.4?  Why?  Note from [J2SE 1.4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html) *"**J2SE 1.4.2 is in its Java Technology End of Life (EOL) transition period.** The EOL transition period began Dec, 11 2006 and will complete October 30th, 2008, when J2SE 1.4.2 will have reached its End of Service Life (EOSL)."*

Comment: this is going to be our last release in this version, the app runs on  SAP J2ee server which supports only 1.4. thanks for reply..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of your solution if I understood your question correctly then your input would be a array (which contains duplicates) and output would be list of duplicate arrays. I have simple approch towards this problem that is a `Map` where `Integer` would be the key and `List` would be the value. Written a little snippet(java 1.4 supported) below.

```
Map map = new HashMap();
int[] array = {121,122,121,122,123,121,122};
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(map.get(array[i])==null){ // no entry available
         List list = new ArrayList();
         list.add(array[i]);
         map.put(array[i],list);
    }else // entry is already available
       map.get(array[i]).add(array[i]);
}
```

I know you have constraint with java version though this could be easier with google [collection library - guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s [MultiSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html). *Library is for Java 1.6+*.

Snippet -

```
Multiset<Inetger> multiSet = HashMultiset.create();
int[] array = {121,122,121,122,123,121,122};
multiSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
for (Inetger i : multiSet.elementSet()) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + multiSet.count(i));
}
```